# Locus of points whose distance difference is a constant to three (or more) points

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, locus

Given two points on a plane, the locus of points with a constant distance difference is a hyperbola.

What happens if there are three points on the plane? Concretely, if there are three points A, B, and C, I'm looking for locus of all points X such that $|XA - XB| = |XB-XC| = |XC - XA| = constant$.

Intuitively, it seems like no such points exist as the three hyperbola don't intersect at same points. How to make this formal?

Comment: How do you define the difference between three points?

Comment: I meant the pairwise distance difference between any two points. I will clarify it in the post

Comment: Do the three points have to be on the same plane?

Comment: Yes, they do. (Clarified in the post)